# How do i resize a widget in WxPython using GridSizer

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython, sizer

**Introduction and Issue**

I've made a gridsizer to resize my frame itself.

But because of the gridsizer if I use `WX_EXPAND` flag (to let them have a new height and width when I use `self.Layout()` to refresh when the app is resized) they don't resize the % of the screen I gave them (I put blank widget to put all my widget where I want).

Example [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/468077116123250689/803631586149924934/unknown.png)

**What I have tried**

I've tried to make a `wx.GridBagSizer` but I can't understand why it always say that GenericTreeCtrl don't exist (its a must I need this tree) so I'm asking a way to do this with `wx.GridSizer`.

I want to work with something like that and be able to resize my widget: [what I want to be resizable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5oos.png)

**Question**

Can you please tell me whats the correct and optimal way to dynamically resize a widget using a `wx.GridSizer`?

```
class mainPanel(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent, pageNum, FrameSize):
    self.parent = parent
    self.pageNum = pageNum
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
    Sizer = wx.GridSizer(6,6,0,0)
    self.PathList = []
    self.PathSelected = []
    self.pastePath = ""
    self.SetSizer(Sizer)


    #tree
    widthA,heightA = FrameSize[0],FrameSize[1]
    path = "/media/" + os.getlogin()
    self.folder_tree_project = wx.GenericDirCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,path, (0,0), wx.Size(widthA*0.3,heightA*0.75),wx.FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE|wx.DIRCTRL_MULTIPLE)
    Sizer.Add(self.folder_tree_project,0,wx.LEFT,0)
    self.t1 = self.folder_tree_project.GetTreeCtrl()
    self.folder_tree_project.ShowHidden(False)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_SEL_CHANGED, self.OnSelect,id=self.t1.GetId())

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnResize)

    #--------------------------------------------------------
    
def OnResize(self,event):
    FrameSize = self.GetSize()
    self.Sizer.Layout()
```

Comment: Yes it doesn't resize my widget they are still the same (https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/468077116123250689/803635788079956048/unknown.png)
It's in my notebook, framesize is used to give % of it's size for the widget size depending on wich widget.

Comment: can you please post your code or the smallest reproducible example where your issue happens?

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/468077116123250689/803639786682056714/unknown.png is this good like that ? i forgot to move it but i also use self.SetSizer(sizer)

Comment: please don't post photo or links for code, write it as a snippet in your question

Comment: Done tell me if there something to change again. Never posted on forum before and my english is not that good sorry for the inconvenient

Comment: if they din't resize is because you don't do anything in yout OnReszie function

Comment: It change nothing they keep the initiale size, also it's strange to be able to resize the appsize i just have to do a self.Layout in the frame init (when i call OnResize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not be able to test it Leonardo but thanks for the reply ! (i did not answered because of the Global Game Jam that i was participating)
I've found another way thanks to someone on another forum, using the app 'WxGlade' I was able to understand how GridBagSizer work.
You can't do things like GenericDirCtrl in WxGlade but I've read the code given by it by putting button and blank text like I want and putting gridbagsizer, with the previsualization and the generated code I was able to understand how GridBagSizer work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def OnResize(self,event):
    FrameSize = self.GetSize()
    widthA,heightA = FrameSize[0],FrameSize[1]
    self.folder_tree_project.SetSize((int(widthA*0.3),int(heightA*0.75)))
    self.Sizer.Layout()
```